# Non linear phase portrait

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider the (nonlinear) system,
> $ \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
> \dot x=|y|,\\
> \dot y=-x.
> \end{array} \right.$
>
> Sketch the phase portrait of the system.

I have tried to sketch for cases $y > 0$ and $y < 0$.

This a decoupled system and I want to think it looks like an absolute value graph with everything moving away there, and I have no idea what this looks like. Could someone give me a hint?

I have tried to solve each system separately by splitting the variables and integrating. I get $x(t)=|y|(t+c)$ and $y(t)=-x(t+c)$ but this doesn't tell me much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To keep questions and answers together, the etiquitte is to have one question at a time unless related. Look at MathJax in FAQ for formatting. Regards

Comment: Alright i removes the second question, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the vector field at some simple points and plotting it and seeing what you get

Comment: I am not sure how to do that I have never seen a non linear system graphed before. And there isn't one in my linear differential equations textbook.

Comment: "this a decoupled system" Quite the contrary, the system is very much coupled since $x'$ involves $y$ and $y'$ involves $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method I have found for graphing phase planes is as follows.

1. Find the nullclines of $x$ and $y$. These are the lines where $x'$ and $y'$ equal zero. They are important because in each region separated by the nullclines, the sign of $x'$ and $y$ doesn't change. Furthermore, on the nullclines, you know that vector field is parallel to one of the coordinate axes on the nullcline.
   In your case, $|y|=0\Rightarrow y=0$ is the $x$ nullcline, this is where $x'=0$
   For the $y$ nullcline, $-x=0\Rightarrow x=0$ is where $y'=0$.
2. In each region, evaluate $x'$ and $y'$ to determine the direction of the vectors in that region. Your nullclines split the graph into 4 regions: $x>0,y>0$; $x>0,y<0$; $x<0,y>0$; and $x<0,y<0$. Checking each of the regions
   $$
   \begin{array}{cccc}
   x>0&y>0&x'>0&y'<0\\
   x>0&y<0&x'>0&y'<0\\
   x<0&y>0&x'>0&y'>0\\
   x<0&y<0&x'>0&y'>0
   \end{array}
   $$

Here is an image for the final result (on a mobile device, so I can't edit the unnecessary parts out):
[image]

Comment: That is really really weird looking... my prof must be crazy to think I'd know how to draw that! I have a dynamical systems andnonlinear/chaos textbook for ant or class I am going to see if it mentions these nullclines and give it a try. Ty for explaining this